# jest: expect.arrayContaining with order

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to match called with an array with order?

For example, I have tried, but failed as it ignore order:

```
expect(fn()).toBeCalledWith(expect.arrayContaining([1,2,3]))
```

My goal is success when calling with `[1,2,3]` `[1,2,3,4]` `[1,10,2,7,8,9,3]` but not `[3,2,1]`
The above code give me pass when called with `[3,2,1]`, how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This end up can be done with `expect.extend`, which I can create my custom matcher.
https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers

```
expect.extend({
  arrayContainingWithOrder(received, sample) {
    let index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < received.length; i++) {
      if (received[i] === sample[index]) {
        index++;
      }
    }

    const pass = index === sample.length;

    if (pass) {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `expected ${received} not to be contain ${sample} with order`,
        pass: true,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () =>
          `expected ${received} to be contain ${sample} with order`,
        pass: false,
      };
    }
  },
});
```